# Is there a standard way to debounce events in Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, events

I'm looking for something similar to [jQuery throttle/debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/), but for Silverlight. We'd like to debounce a selection-changed event in our Silverlight app - so if the user changes the selection rapidly in quick succession, we only react to the change when the user has stopped changing it.

I don't think this would be hard to write, and I'm not looking for sample code - just wondering whether this is already built in or available in some common library. If not, I'll roll my own using a DispatcherTimer.

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event throttling is not built-in into silverlight. Before you go off and implement your own version I would take a look at [reactive extensions for silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577610). One of the functions is called exactly that: Throttle and it does that it's name implies. The only problem I have with reactive extensions is that dlls are kinda big, so if you must keep you xap file small you might want to go with your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks Denis! That's good to know. I had read about Reactive Extensions but I've never tried it out - it sounds pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

Reactive Extensions is very powerful, but I had to roll my own for a project.  Here it is:

```
using System.Timers;
public static class EventExtensions {
    static Dictionary<EventHandler, Timer> _debounceTimers;

    public static EventHandler Debounce(TimeSpan interval, Action<object, EventArgs> action) {
        object lastSender = null;
        EventArgs lastArgs = null;

        var timer = new Timer();
        if (_debounceTimers == null)
            _debounceTimers = new Dictionary<EventHandler, Timer>();

        timer.Interval = interval.TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            timer.Stop();

            action(lastSender, lastArgs);
        };

        EventHandler handler = (sender, args) => {
            lastSender = sender;
            lastArgs = args;

            timer.Stop();
            timer.Start();
            timer.Enabled = true;
        };

        _debounceTimers.Add(handler, timer);

        return handler;
    }

    public static void DisposeDebouncers(this EventHandler handler) {
        handler.ThrowIfNull("handler");

        if (_debounceTimers.ContainsKey(handler)) {
            var timer = _debounceTimers[handler];
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.Stop();
                timer.Enabled = false;
                timer.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Test

```
using Xunit;
public class EventExtensionsTest {

    event EventHandler FrequentEvent;

    [Fact]
    void DebounceTest() {
        var counter = 0;
        var span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        var handler = EventExtensions.Debounce(span, (sender, e) => counter++);
        FrequentEvent += handler;

        FrequentEvent(this, null);
        FrequentEvent(this, null);
        FrequentEvent(this, null);

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Assert.Equal(1, counter);

        FrequentEvent(this, null);
        FrequentEvent(this, null);
        FrequentEvent(this, null);
        FrequentEvent(this, null);
        FrequentEvent(this, null);

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Assert.Equal(2, counter);

        FrequentEvent.DisposeDebouncers();
        FrequentEvent -= handler;
    }
}
```

`object.ThrowIfNull()` is an extension method that throws an ArgumentNullException if the object is null.  I'm sure there are uncovered edge cases.